# Can't find Identity & Access tab in MVC4 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wif

I have an annoying problem for wich i don't find a direct answer online. I need to add some secuirity to a website we're developping for reservations in a welness center. The task is, add authentication via Azure Active Directory Access Control, so users can login with their Facebook, messenger or google account. I've already implimented Access Control on a few sites, never had any difficulties until now. The Identity & Access tab is missing. I already uninstalled/reinstalled the identity & access tools several times without any success. Does anybody have an idea what might cause this problem? This is an MVC4 project by the way.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the answer. To be able to see and use the identity and access dialogue screen, you need to set your mvc app to a .NET Framework 4.5 project, restart your program and you'll see the Identity & Access tab when you right click your project.

[image: Target framework]

Comment: I must be doing something wrong when the entire Internet says that the "Identity and Access" menu entry should be right there below the "Add Solution to Source Control" entry, when right clicking the .NET 4.5 project in VS2012, after having installed the plugin, restarted VS2012, dotted the i's and crossed the t's. Still it is NOT where I am told it should be. I must be cursed :-/

Comment: @Jeff, no. I had to move on to a new project, so I'm sad to say that I left it in a must-be-voodoo-state. No conclusion.